# Opengles Surface(EglSurface) resizing causes black screen on android

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es

To resize the Egl surface, i am destroying current surface and creating new surface with new size, but in-between these operation, it shows black screen after the destroy operation.

How can i avoid this behaviour ?
i am using opengles 2.0 lib on android.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating the new surface with the new size swapping it out with the old version THEN destroying the old surface.